# Can `public <T extends Number> T method( Integer x ) {...}` take input of a type that extends Integer?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, integer

I am confused by one of the questions on my practice exam.

> In Java, the Integer class extends the base abstract class Number. Now, suppose
>   we have a method with a signature as follows:
>
> `public <T extends Number> T method( Integer x ) {...}`
>
> For each of the following, write “can” or “cannot” into the blanks to correctly complete
>   the statement.
>
> The method ______ take any input of a type that extends Integer

I am confused because when I try to make my own class that extends Integer, IntelliJ tells me, "Cannot inherit from final 'java.lang.Integer'".

If I can't inherit from the Integer class, then how would I give input that "extends Integer" in the first place?

Comment: Well, its a typical bad exam question with an unclear question text where either the asker tried to be clever in asking something out of scope or they failed in creating a proper example. I would pick "cannot" and write next to the text why I chose that answer.

Comment: The method can take any input of a type that extends Integer. But there is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That statement is pretty badly formulated. I hope it was written like that for confusing the student, and not because they forgot primitive types' wrappers are `final` classes.

So, to answer your question, the answer would be "*cannot*".
But if you can, clarify this point with your professor or examiner.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). You can't extend a class that is declared final

Answer (score 0):

The Integer class for Java is `final`, it can't be inherit.

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```